# Convert LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Accounts>
  <Account id="usama" password="3210" lastUpdated="6/16/2011 11:21:59 AM" nextUpdate="6/16/2011 11:36:59 AM">
    <SubAccount id="false">
      <Url>yahoo</Url>
      <Review>not so good</Review>
    </SubAccount>
    <SubAccount id="false">
      <Url>google</Url>
      <Review>as good as heard.</Review>
    </SubAccount>
  </Account>
</Accounts>
```

Let suppose I want to get all those results whose last Updated date is less than  or equal today(suppose 6/17/2011) date.

So my result should look like this.

```
Accout id =usama ,passwod =3210 ,url=yahoo, review=not so good
Accout id =usama ,passwod =3210 ,url=google, review=as good as heard
```

I have written the query so far

```
var q = from c in doc.Descendants("Accounts")
        from a in c.Descendants("Account")
        where a.Attribute("nextUpdate").Value == "6/16/2011 11:36:59 AM"
        select new
               {                        
                 accountName = a.Attribute("id").Value,                       
                 password = a.Attribute("password").Value,                        
                 url = a.Descendants("SubAccount").Descendants("Url").ToString() 
                 //review=a.Attribute("nextUpdate").Value
               }
```

I am getting the user name and password fine but I do not know how to get URL and review. Also how to cast Attribute("nextUpdate") in where clause to date time so that I can compare it with date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (tested and works):

```
DateTime someTime = DateTime.Now;
var q = from a in doc.Descendants("Account")
        from sub in a.Elements("SubAccount")
        where (DateTime)a.Attribute("nextUpdate") <= someTime 
        select new
        {  
            accountName = a.Attribute("id").Value,  
            password = a.Attribute("password").Value,  
            url = (string)sub.Element("Url").Value,
            review = (string)sub.Element("Review").Value
        }
```

This uses the `DateTime` cast provided by Linq to XML (also see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343203.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var q =
    from account in doc.Descendants("Account")
    from subAcount in account.Elements("SubAccount")
    where DateTime.Parse(account.Attribute("nextUpdate").Value) == filterDateTime
    select new
    {
        accountName = account.Attribute("id").Value,
        password = account.Attribute("password").Value,
        url = subAcount.Element("Url").Value,
        review = subAcount.Element("Review").Value
    };
```

`filterDateTime` is a variable of `DateTime`.

Comment: this will only return a result for the first `SubAccount` element within an account, so not what OP wants.

Comment: Thanks!But this query gives me first element in a node.so it returns    Accout id =usama ,passwod =3210 ,url=yahoo, review=not so good only .I also want 2nd one as asked in question.

Comment: @Zain, @BrokenGlass - yes, I overlooked multiple subaccounts in the xml. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my proposal.

```
var doc = XElement.Load(...);
var q =
    from account in doc.Elements("Account")
    let nextUpdate = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(account.Attribute("nextUpdate").Value, "your date format").Date
    where nextUpdate <= DateTime.Today
    from subAccount in account.Elements("SubAccount")
    select new
    { 
      Id = account.Attribute("id").Value,
      Password = account.Attribute("password").Value,
      Url = subAccount.Element("Url").Value,
      Review= subAccount.Element("Review").Value,
    }
```

Don't forget to replace "your date format" with an appropriate format string.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzk5c6y9.aspx